# Unpivot table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot

I have the below table as a result of SUM(Case....End).

```
Account            Product_A            Product_B           Product_C
101                 1000                  2000                 3000
102                 2000                  1000                  0
103                 2000                  1000                  0
104                 2000                  1000                  2000
```

I want to return it back to the original table. Like this:

```
Account         Product               Qty
101               A                  1000
...               ..                 ....
```

I think "Unpivot" can do it in MS SQL Server. But I use only PostgreSQL.
What is the equivalent of Unpivot in Postgresql that can return/ungroup the above table?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use a lateral join with a values clause:

```
select t.account, u.product, u.qty
from the_table t
  cross join lateral ( 
     values ('A',product_a), ('B', product_b), ('C', product_c)
  ) as u(product, qty)
order by t.account;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5b0f8bfd0d57fd0454a4d585f1237f9b)

Answer (score 2):

I think simply `unnest` will help you:

```
SELECT Account,
       unnest(array['A', 'B', 'C']) AS Product,
       unnest(array[Product_A, Product_B, Product_C]) AS Qty
FROM test
ORDER BY Account;
```

[FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f415534d6c50f0c3b837c338169738a3)

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically unpivot those columns even if more column (such as `Product_D`) is added to the table by means of using JSON functions :

```
SELECT account, UPPER(SPLIT_PART((js).key, '_', 2)) AS Product, (js).value AS Qty 
  FROM( SELECT rj->>'account' AS Account, JSON_EACH_TEXT(rj) AS js
          FROM ( SELECT ROW_TO_JSON(t) AS rj FROM t) AS q1 ) AS q2
 WHERE (js).key != 'account';
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9f46e6492e6e7610a32b5332741e5ce8)</kbd>

while splitting the column names of the Products depending on the pattern defined for the existing column names (`Product_A/B/C`) without explicitly specifying each letter.