# SQL Select greatest and get the column name

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, unpivot

I have such table (simplified)

| id | pos | neu | neg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| y | 4 | 2 | 1 |
| z | 1 | 5 | 2 |

I use PostgreSQL and my goal is to get greatest value for each row, so i use next query:

```
SELECT id, GREATEST(pos, neg, neu) FROM my_table;
```

In response i have smth like:

| id | greatest |
| --- | --- |
| x | 3 |
| y | 4 |
| z | 5 |

But is there a way i can know which column these values are belong to?

Expected smth like:

| id | greatest | column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 3 | neg |
| y | 4 | pos |
| z | 5 | neu |

Comment: Assuming you have more than those 3 columns in your actual table, I guess [UNPIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64268037/205233) would be the way to go here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a case expression such as this:

```
select id, greatest(pos, neg, neu),
  case greatest(pos, neg, neu) 
    when pos then 'pos' 
    when neg then 'neg' 
    when neu then 'neu' 
  end as ColumnName
from t;
```

Comment: Great! As for me, the most smooth solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is an elegant solution that is independent of the number of columns:

```sql
select distinct on (id) 
    id, 
    value as greatest, 
    key as column
from my_table t
cross join jsonb_each(to_jsonb(t)- 'id')
order by id, value desc;
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/DskBDddE)

Comment: the 'not-so' elegant part is the `ORDER BY .... value desc`, with results showing in ascending order.  ., but finally a good use of a json related function!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend unpivoting the columns to rows with a lateral join, then using `distinct on` to get the top column/value pair per `id`:

```
select distinct on (t.id) t.id, x.*
from mytable t
cross join lateral ( values ('pos', t.pos), ('neu', t.neu), ('neg', t.neg) ) x(col, val)
order by t.id, x.val desc, x.col
                        -- ^ tie-breaker
```

On a large dataset, it *might* be more efficient to move the row-limitng logic within the lateral join:

```
select t.id, x.*
from mytable t
cross join lateral ( 
    select x.*
    from ( values ('pos', t.pos), ('neu', t.neu), ('neg', t.neg) ) x(col, val)
    order by x.val desc, x.col
    limit 1
) x
```

| id | col | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | neg | 3 |
| y | pos | 4 |
| z | neu | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Rm30IJQy)